# edit existing key flexfield in oracle apps

Tags: oracle, oracle-apps

The company that i am attached with is implementing Oracle HCM for this other organization. The organization already has Oracle Payroll module in use. They want HCM integrated with the existing payroll. The company does not have anyone who specializes in any of the Oracle E-Business Suite modules, so I am given that task even though I have no experience with any of the Oracle technologies. My real question is as follows:

On the business requirements and mapping documents that I have, key flexfields, (specifically the Job and position Flexfields) are have different structures and segments from the ones that are already in use by the payroll.

Can I change already defined key flexfields, and if i do so, what will happen to the already existing payroll data, will i be able to create new jobs, and stuff.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, once Key Flexfield structures have been defined you are not supposed to change them. Changing a Key Flexfield structure may invalidate underlying data from transactions as well as invalidate the Value Sets. However, there are some exceptions, but it will take a finding someone with a deep understanding of the affected modules, finding approved update scripts, and extensive testing.

A good place to start is on [My Oracle Support](https://support.oracle.com). Search on the module name and "key flexfields" and see what you find. You can also log a Service Request with Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

A safe way would be to add segments to the already existing keyflex segments. As long as the combination remains unique (hence: *key*), all should be fine.

But in Payroll one can have formulas checking for particular job / position names, so these needs revision.

Or payroll  setup has been done to have percentages or amounts linked to such organizations, jobs, positions, ...